# c# Document.All doesn't get currently displayed in webbrowser after a click

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, htmlelements

i opened an URL using webbrowser into a C# project framework 4.

When i do:

```
                foreach (HtmlElement ele in webBrowser1.Document.All)
                {
                    if (ele.GetAttribute("className") == "clickMe")
                        ele.InvokeMember("Click");
                }
```

In pure Javascript is:

```
document.getElementByClassName("getMe")[0].click()
```

that will appear a new button clickable.

The problem is when i want to click on the new button created after that click:

```
                foreach (HtmlElement elem in webBrowser1.Document.All)
                {
                    if (elem.GetAttribute("className") == "newButton")
                        elem.InvokeMember("Click");
                }
```

i put this code in the middle but nothing:

```
                while (this.webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                {
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
```

So, the problem is that webbrowser doesn't change the html dinamically after first click on clickMe class attribute.
clickMe is the class of HTML "a" Tag (the tag has some attribute)

Comment: In the HTML, is the name of the attribute you want to detect "class" (e.g. `class="clickMe"`) or "className" (e.g. `className="clickMe"`)?

Comment: The attribute is class='clickMe'. The problem is for class='newButton' it doesn't exist and I don't know the problem.  Using Javascript the new element is created after click()  on element with class='clickMe'

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript injection.

```
HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
element.text = "function clickMe() { document.getElementByClassName('getMe')[0].click() }";
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("clickMe");
```